# Removing Extended Wrap Method From Highcharts.wrap

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

How am I able to manually remove/undo a wrap on a Highcharts Class Prototype?

I currently have this in a class in Angular and it seems like the wrap is holding onto my method as a closure even after the component is destroyed.

```js
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
export class ExampleComponent implements OnDestroy
     constructor() {
         function logRefresh(H) {
             H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function(proceed, point) {
                 proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
                 console.log(proceed, point);
             });
         }
         logRefresh(Highcharts);
     }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The wrap method overwrites an original function in Highcharts prototype, so it is a permanent change. You can check how the method exactly works [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/Core/Utilities.ts#L858-L878).

As a solution, you can store an original function somewhere, for example:

```
H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function(proceed) {
  console.log('refresh');

  if (!H.Tooltip.prototype.refreshOriginal) {
    H.Tooltip.prototype.refreshOriginal = proceed;
  }

  proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
});
```

---

And restore it when you want.

```
const tooltipProto = H.Tooltip.prototype;
// restore original refresh function
tooltipProto.refresh = tooltipProto.refreshOriginal;
delete tooltipProto.refreshOriginal;
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nfqcwhk6/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Your JS fiddle is throwing error on hover

Comment: Hi @Arokia Lijas, That's because the `refresh` method wasn't called in 2000 milliseconds period. You can call it manually when the chart is loaded, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6huj1t92/

Comment: How do I destroy or remove this wrap function? Even if the component is destroyed this function is not destroyed. I'm using the chart as a child component and whenever a date is changed I use ngIf to destroy the chart component and make the ngIf true again. But the console log that I put in wrap is getting increased, initially there will be 1 log when I change date it there will be two and the count keeps increasing. I destroy the chartref on ngOnDestroy and remove the addedEvent of mousewheel as well. This is the code that I used http://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/gcqn1zpu/

Comment: You don't need to use `wrap` in your case. Using `chart.load` event will be enough. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gj50d6nw/