# Remove Extended Wrap Method From HighChart after the component is destroyed

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

```
H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'render', function (proceed) {
  var chart = this,

  proceed.call(chart);
  // Add the mousewheel event to make vertical scroll
  H.addEvent(chart.container,'mousewheel', function (event) {

    let delta, extr, step,  axis = chart.yAxis[0];

    let e = chart.pointer.normalize(event);
    // Firefox uses e.detail, WebKit and IE uses wheelDelta
    delta = e.detail || (e.wheelDelta / 120);
    delta = delta < 0 ? 1 : -1;
    extr = axis.getExtremes();
    const min = extr.min;
    const max = extr.max;
    const dataMax = extr.dataMax;
    if (chart.isInsidePlot(e.chartX - chart.plotLeft, e.chartY - chart.plotTop) && (min > 1 || (min < 1 && delta === 1)) && (max < dataMax || (max >= dataMax && delta === -1))) {
      step = (extr.max - extr.min) / 5 * delta;
      axis.setExtremes(extr.min + step, extr.max + step, true, false);
    }
    globalObj.stopEvent(event); // Issue #5011, returning false from non-jQuery event does not prevent default
    return false;
  });
})
```

I'm destroying the chart ing ngOndestroy and when I come back again to the same the component the previous closure which was created is still not destroyed. I need to remove the wrap function when the component is destroyed.

Comment: Hi @Arokia Lijas, That's probably a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70042901/removing-extended-wrap-method-from-highcharts-wrap/70066785 - please check the answer in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

After a suggestion from @ppotaczek I removed the Wrap function and called my add event function after the chart is created.

```
const globalObj = this;
this.highchartRef = Highcharts.ganttChart('container', this.chartOptions, function(chartObj){
  globalObj.addMouseWheelEvent(chartObj); //Called my add mouse wheel event
});
```